# Is it reasonable to report $I^2=0$ with confidence interval [0, 100] in a meta analysis?

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, heterogeneity

Is it reasonable to report $I^2$=0 with 95% confidence interval [0, 100] in a meta analysis manuscript?
I was not sure since the CI covers all possible values.

$I^2$ is a commonly used heterogeneity measure that provides an estimate of the proportion of variability in a meta-analysis that is explained by differences between the included studies rather than by sampling error. In my meta-analysis, I only have 2 studies which is a small number for this kind of analysis, and it may be reason for having this wide CI.

Comment: What is this $I^2$ score?

Comment: With only two studies the estimate is bound to be very imprecise and so the wide CI is not at all surprising.

Comment: @mdewey true.  I was not sure if there is a point of reporting this. Maybe I should just mentioned about it and the issue of having only 2 studies. Thx for the comment.